# Sacar dos listas de un fichero

Tags: python, spyder

Tengo un fichero de la siguiente forma:

```
Estudiante 1: Manuel Santos
Lengua->8->Matematicas->10->Sociales->9->Recreo
Estudiante 2: Iris Garcia
Lengua->5->Matematicas->9->Sociales->4->Recreo
```

Y así hasta 16 alumnos. En las lineas pares está el nombre de los estudiantes mientras que en las impares se encuentra la información de las asignaturas con las notas. Necesito crear una función que me devuelva el fichero en un diccionario de la siguiente manera:

```
{'Estudiante 1: Manuel Santos' : [Lengua, Matematicas, Sociales, Recreo], [8, 10, 9] , 'Estudiante 2: ...}
```

La clave sería el nombre del estudiante y los valores serían dos listas, una de ellas con las asignaturas y otra con las notas. Está claro que el `Recreo` se incluye pero no tiene nota. Por lo que habría n asignaturas y n-1 notas.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
 def separar_est(filename):
    lista = []
    lista_asignaturas = []
    lista_notas = []
    estudiantes_file = open(filename, 'r')
    lineas = estudiantes_file.readlines()  #lineas es una lista
    for linea in lineas:
        linea = linea.split(sep = '->')
        lista.append(linea)
    #print(lista)
    for i in range(1, len(lista), 2):
        print(lista[i])
        for j in range(0, len(lista[i])-1):
            print(lista[j])
            lista_asignaturas.append(lista[j-1])
            lista_notas.append(lista[j])
        
    return lista_asignaturas, lista_notas
```

Estoy intentando que esta función me de las dos listas que necesito pero no consigo que me las devuelva.

Answer (score 2):

El diccionario que propones está mal formado, no puedes tener valores sin clave (key). Supondré que los valores deben ser una lista de sublistas:

Diccionario incorrecto

```
{'Estudiante 1: Manuel Santos' : [Lengua, Matematicas, Sociales, Recreo], [8, 10, 9], ...}
```

Suposición, con estructura correcta:

```
{'Estudiante 1: Manuel Santos' : [['Lengua', 'Matematicas', 'Sociales', 'Recreo'], [8, 10, 9]], ...}
```

El siguiente código busca un `key` en las líneas que empiezan con `"Estudiante"`. Si esa línea no empieza con esa palabra, entonces será la de materias. A esta línea se le hace un *replace* con expresiones regulares. El reemplazo con `:` es arbitrario, pero conveniente, ya que la primera línea tiene una *pseudodivisión* con dos puntos, entonces sería sencillo hacer una partición de *key:value* por cada registro completo y armar un diccionario como uno quisiera, como el que describo en la última parte de este post.

De una línea con los datos:

```
Lengua->8->Matematicas->10->Sociales->9->Recreo
```

Después de aplicarle `re.sub()` quedará:

```
Lengua:8,Matematicas:10,Sociales:9,Recreo
```

Finalmente esa línea se envía a una función la cual dividirá en subcadenas separada por comas y luego esa subcadena por los `:`. La línea `notas.append(None)` la puedes quitar si no necesitas ese valor. Lo puse para que fuera correspondiente la cantidad de materias con notas.

```
import re

def split_data(li):
    materias = [] 
    notas = []
    for elem in li.split(','):
        pos = elem.find(':')
        if pos > 0:
            materias.append(elem[:pos])
            notas.append(int(elem[pos+1:]))
        else:
            materias.append(elem)
            notas.append(None)
    return [materias, notas]
            

lista_notas = {}
key = ''
with open('stack019.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        linea = line.strip()
        if linea.startswith('Estudiante'):
            key = linea
        elif key != '' and linea != '':
            data = re.sub(r'->([0-9]+)->', r':\1,', linea)
            value = split_data(data)
            lista_notas[key] = value
            key = ''
        else:
            pass

print(lista_notas)
```

Da como resultado

```
{'Estudiante 1: Manuel Santos': [['Lengua', 'Matematicas', 'Sociales', 'Recreo'], [8, 10, 9, None]], 
'Estudiante 2: Iris Garcia': [['Lengua', 'Matematicas', 'Sociales', 'Recreo'], [5, 9, 4, None]]}
```

---

Ahora bien, considero que de todas formas lo anterior no es un diccionario bien estructurado, por ende no es muy útil.

Un diccionario más descriptivo, podría tener los datos de esta forma:

```
estudiantes = {
    "id":"1",
    "nombre":"Manuel Santos",
    "materias": {
        "Lengua":8,
        "Matematicas":10,
        "Sociales":9,
        "Recreo":None
    },
    "id":"2",
    "nombre":"Iris Garcia",
    "materias": {
        "Lengua":5,
        "Matematicas":9,
        "Sociales":4,
        "Recreo":None
    }
}
```

Pero ese ya requerirá otra modificación en el código.

Answer (score 0):

en el resultado que buscas está mal declarado el diccionario, tampoco entiendo el porque no usar solo el nombre del estudiante como clave(así lo hago) y tu función devuelve dos listas, hago la función que retorne el diccionario, aunque podrías retornar las listas.

```
def separar_est(archivo):
    diccionario = {}
    with open(archivo) as archivo:
        for linea in enumerate(archivo):
            if linea[0] % 2 == 0:
                temp = linea[1].split(":")
                clave= temp[1][:-1]
            else:
                temp= linea[1].split("->")
                materias=[x.rstrip('\n') for x in temp if temp.index(x) %2 == 0]
                notas=[int(x) for x in temp if temp.index(x) %2 != 0]
                valor=[materias,notas]
                diccionario.setdefault(clave,valor)
    return diccionario
```

en base a tu código no hay nada nuevo, salvo que uso with con la apertura de archivos porque esta implícito el close, que no está en tu función y debería,
además uso enumerate, porque prefiero analizar cada línea por separado en vez de que sea una lista total.